# Prove that there is a natural injection $V ′/U^0 → U′$ which is also surjective when V is finite dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following problem:

Let U be a subspace of V. Prove that there is a natural injection $V ′/U^0 → U′$ which is also surjective when V is finite dimensional.

Here, $V'$ and $U'$ are dual spaces and $U^0$ is the annihilator of U.

I've managed to do this with a long proof involving bases. Is there a quicker way I missed (possibly using one of the isomorphism theorems)? And why does dim(V) have to be finite in order for it to be surjective?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\phi\in V'$, i.e., $\phi$ is a linear map $V\to k$.
Then the restriction $\phi|_U$ is a linear map $U\to k$. The kernel of the map $\operatorname{res}\colon V'\to U'$, $\phi\mapsto \phi|_U$ is, by definition, $U^0$. By the isomorphism theorems, the image of $\operatorname{res}$ is isomorphic to  $V'/U^0$, thus giving us (in a natural way) an injection $V'/U^0\to U'$.

Let $W$ be a complement of $U$ in $V$, i.e., we can write $V=U\oplus W$. Then given any $\psi\in U'$, we can combine this with $0\in W'$ to a linear map on $V$ that restricts to $\psi$. We conclude that the restriction is surjective.
The existence of such a complement $W$ is clear if $\dim V<\infty$. In the infinite-dimensional case, it requires the Axiom of Choice (but if you do not accept that here, you do not even have that all vectors spaces have bases).